# Trying to compare the contents two Iterators, how?

Tags: java, input, iterator, compare, listiterator

EDIT: With your help I managed to fix my problem. I have edited my code to now show how I had to have it set up to get it working.

Currently I am having trouble coding a part which compares the content of two iterators. As part of the requirements for my assignment, I need to use a linkedlist to store the individual characters of the entered String. I have gotten to the point where I have two iterators which would contain the input one way and the reverse way.

```
        String palindrom = input.getText();
        String [] chara = palindrom.split (""); //this is successfully splitting them, tested.


        int length = palindrom.length( ); // length == 8
        System.out.println (length); //can use this for how many checks to do?
        LinkedList ll = new LinkedList(Arrays.asList(chara));


        Iterator iterator = ll.iterator();
        Iterator desIterator = ll.descendingIterator();

        /*while(iterator.hasNext() ){
            System.out.println(iterator.next() );
        }

        while(desIterator.hasNext() ){
            System.out.println(desIterator.next() );
        }*/
        boolean same = true;
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            if(!iterator.next().equals(desIterator.next())){
            same = false;
            break;
          }
        }
```

And using the System.out I can see that they are being stored correctly, but I don't know how to check if the iterators store the same contents. What would be one of the simplest methods to compare the two iterators or convert them into something I can compare? To clarify I want to verify they contain the same elements in the same order.

Comment: To clarify, do you want to confirm that both iterators just have the same elements, or that both iterators have the same elements, in the same order.

Comment: This isn't really the problem here. OP is iterating through both iterators to output the values, after which both iterators are "empty" and will therefore be recognized as "equal". You should create new iterators for comparing.

Comment: Ok so I replaced that line with the line I had but its still returning that all of my wrong inputs are true. Anything else you can think I might need to fix? The print also now outputs random garbles of text.    

Also I want them to have the same elements in the same order. Sorry for being vague.

Comment: It is not working because you already looped through the iterators when you were printing them out.  So by the time you reach the actual logic, the iterator has no elements left.  Comment out the two while-loops and try it again.

Comment: @user286152 You definitely don't want to do `Arrays.asList(palindrom.toCharArray())`. `Arrays.asList` doesn't work for a `char[]`. Your original set up was fine, but you need to use the version with the line `if(!iterator.next().equals(desIterator.next()))` as you are comparing `Strings`.

Comment: @pbabcdefp hey that helped me get it working, thanks so much. also thank you satnam for helping me by giving me the orignal part and working with me through it earlier.

Comment: @user286152 Glad we could help. Make sure that you include the full program next time you ask as it's so much easier to help. I assumed you were using a `LinkedList<Character>`. If you had been, the `!=` solution would have worked, due to instance caching. Also don't use the raw type `LinkedList`. It's a `LinkedList<String>`! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
boolean same = true;
while(iterator.hasNext()){
  if(!desIterator.hasNext() || !iterator.next().equals(desIterator.next())){
    same = false;
    break;
  }
}

System.out.println(same);
```

Comment: This seems to always be returning true. When I type "fish" into the input, I can see iterator has f i s h and desIterator has h s i f but it still says that they are true. I believe this is because your solution merely checks for the contents and not the order, I should have been more specific. How would I do this if I needed to take into account the order? so r a c e c a r and r a c e c a r shows true but not f i s h and h s i f?

Comment: The solution I posted does check both contents and order. You probably didn't set up your list correctly. But you didn't post that code, so I can't help anymore.

Comment: Note that this assumes that both iterators have the same number of elements (given in the question). You should probably compare with `equals`, though.

Comment: Given that both iterators were created off of the same exact list, I think the assumption of them being the same length is valid.

Comment: This solution does work. I just tried it. Comparison should really done using `equals` though as instances of `Character` are only cached for some unicode values.

Comment: @pbabcdefp I'm not disputing that the solution is correct, I was just noting some caveats which need to be considered for the general case of comparing two iterators.

Comment: Sorry I'm not very experienced with programming, I'd assume I didn't store them correctly. I updated my original post with where I store the list if that helps hopefully. I appreciate your time and thanks for your help so far.

Comment: responded to your post with the reason it's not working

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard I know you're not. I meant to tag the OP in my comment, not you. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

You need to iterate over both iterators simultaneously, i.e. with one loop. Here is a general comparison function (0 when equal, < 0 when A < B, > 0 when A > B):

```
static <T extends Comparable<S>, S> int compare(Iterator<T> a, Iterator<S> b) {
    while (a.hasNext() && b.hasNext()) {
        int comparison = a.next().compareTo(b.next());
        if (comparison != 0) {
            return comparison;
        }
    }
    if (a.hasNext())
        return 1;
    if (b.hasNext())
        return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

To just check if they are equal, this can be simplified:

```
static <T, S> boolean equals(Iterator<T> a, Iterator<S> b) {
    while (a.hasNext() && b.hasNext()) {
        if (!a.next().equals(b.next())) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (a.hasNext() || b.hasNext()) {
        // one of the iterators has more elements than the other
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Guava implements this as [Iterators.elementsEqual](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r22/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#elementsEqual%28java.util.Iterator,%20java.util.Iterator%29).

Answer (score 1):

In both answers throw NullPointerException, if iterator.next() == null. This method is more optimal.

```
public static boolean equals(Iterator i1, Iterator i2) {

    if (i1 == i2) {
        return true;
    }
    while (i1.hasNext()) {

        if (!i2.hasNext()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(i1.next(), i2.next())) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (i2.hasNext()) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```